# How to set lower or upper in gorm model when primary key is mixed

Tags: go, grails-orm

I have a table with 3 columns:

- emrID (this is the primary key)
- patient_name (string)
- Comment(string)

This my code

```
import (
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
    "gorm.io/gorm/schema"
)

type Patient_List struct {
    Patient_name string
    EmrID        string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Comment      string
}

func Main() {
    var onePatient Patient_List
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("E://sqlitDB//test.db"), &gorm.Config{
        NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
            SingularTable: true,
        },
    })
    db.Find(&onePatient, "Comment=?", "has Tag with emrID")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("connect err", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf(onePatient.Patient_name)
        fmt.Printf(onePatient.EmrID)
    }
}
```

I got a record `onePatient`, the `onePatient.Patient_name` has a value, but `onePatient.EmrID` is empty.

When I change table columns `emrID` to `emrid`, and change the code to this:

```
type Patient_List struct {
    Patient_name string
    Emrid        string `gorm:"primaryKey"` // EmrID->Emrid
    Comment      string
}
```

it can get data in `onePatient.EmrID`. So if I don't change my table columns, what change in code can make `onePatient.EmrID` has data?

I test some types like

- table: emrID ; struct: Emr_id
- table: emrID ; struct: Emr_ID
- table: emrID ; struct: EmrID

but all of those do not work

Answer (score 0):

If the column names in your database is not in snake-case,then you need to explicitly tell the name of your columns to GORM. For that purpose, you can use the tags when you are creating your struct. In your case you can do the following:

```
type Patient_List struct {
    Patient_name string `gorm:"column:patient_name" json:"patient_name"`
    Emrid        string `gorm:"primaryKey; column:emr_id"`
    Comment      string `gorm:"column:comment" json:"comment"`
}
```

GORM only expects column names with snake case by default. So that, if you want to have column names with for example camel-case or kebab-case, then you have to write those tags in your model.